# Constrain image inside div tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

So this is the code I am working with:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class=" h-48 p-3 bg-gray-700">
  <div class="h-full w-48 bg-gray-700 border border-gray-300">
    <div class="h-6 bg-gray-400 opacity-50 w-full">
      Username
    </div>
    <img class="w-full object-contain" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am having issues getting the image to constrain to the parent div. What I want to accomplish is to have the user image constrain inside the parent div and not overflow outside the border. The image attached is what it looks like now. I have no idea what I am doing wrong or missing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make it a flexbox container

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class=" h-48 p-3 bg-gray-700">
      <div class="h-full w-48 bg-gray-700 border border-gray-300 flex flex-col">
        <div class="h-6 bg-gray-400 opacity-50 w-full">
          Username
        </div>
        <img class="w-full object-contain min-h-0" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

OR CSS grid:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class=" h-48 p-3 bg-gray-700">
      <div class="h-full w-48 bg-gray-700 border border-gray-300 grid">
        <div class="h-6 bg-gray-400 opacity-50 w-full">
          Username
        </div>
        <img class="w-full object-contain min-h-0 h-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330" />
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: OK love both. I am just tired and was not seeing what I was missing. Let me ask you this. How would you put them side by side if you had multiple divs like that?

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zfnehovL/ ?

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan or this too: https://jsfiddle.net/zfnehovL/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex flex-col` on parent container and add `min-h-0` to image.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class=" h-48 p-3 bg-gray-700">
  <div class="h-full w-48 bg-gray-700 border border-gray-300 flex flex-col">
    <div class="h-6 bg-gray-400 opacity-50 w-full">
      Username
    </div>
    <img class="w-full object-contain min-h-0" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG Why didnt I see that. I have been looking at this for 30 min now. I have selected this as the correct answer!